# How to remove middle appearing twice in the name list in r

Tags: r, regex

My name list has the following error where the middle name appears twice for example s.no-1,2. I have the data table format which has 100k observation and 15 variables including name column. How to achieve the expected output by removing the middle name appearing twice?

```
 Name Column               Expected 
 1.A michael michael aura  1.A michael aura
 2.A thomas thomas parsa   2.A thomas parsa
 3.a gul                   3.a gul
 4.clark                   4.clark
```

Comment: What have you tried? Searching for "finding repeats" yields no hits on the internet? Please provide your example in an easy-to-paste form.

Comment: sub("\\s+(\\w+\\s*)\\1+", " \\1", df1[,1])

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub`

```
sub("\\s+(\\w+\\s*)\\1+", " \\1", df1[,1])
#[1] "1.A michael aura" "2.A thomas parsa" "3.a gul"          "4.clark"
```

Comment: Hi I have a similar issue with slight change,

Comment: @DineshKumar if you found this answer helpful consider accepting it as a solution to let the community know it worked for you and to acknowledge the help of the community